# saving multiple 3D array of size (22,6,2840) as images

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am generating multiple 3D numpy array of size (22,6,2840),each array containing 22 array of size(6,2840).Now I want to save this array (22,6,2840) as images. I don't know if I can do that. I tried to do this using `plt.savefig` but it didn't work. I am trying for more than 2 weeks to find how I can do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    signals=np.zeros((22,6,2840))
    t=0
    movement=int(S*256)
    if(S==0):
        movement=_SIZE_WINDOW_SPECTOGRAM        
    while data.shape[1]-(t*movement+_SIZE_WINDOW_SPECTOGRAM) > 0:
        for i in range(0, 22):
            start = t*movement
            stop = start+_SIZE_WINDOW_SPECTOGRAM
            signals[i,:]=wavelet(data[i,start:stop])
        if(signalsBlock is None):
            signalsBlock=np.array([signals])
        else:
            signalsBlock=np.append(signalsBlock, [signals], axis=0)
        nSpectogram=nSpectogram+1
        if(signalsBlock.shape[0]==50):
            saveSignalsOnDisk(signalsBlock, nSpectogram)
            signalsBlock=None
              
        t = t+1
```

Comment: PIL is recommended, thanks

Comment: `plt.savefig` is used for save figures generated by `matplotlib`, not for saving array data to image format.

Comment: @ted930511 How I can use PIL to convert (22,6,2840) to image ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `PyPNG` library. You will have to reshape your array to a 2-D format and then write it as a png. The link to the library is [here](https://pypng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ex.html#numpy-array-to-png-writing)

```
    image_2d = numpy.reshape(image_3d, (-1, column_count * plane_count))
    pngWriter.write(out, image_2d)
```

Also, one more method by using `PIL Image` is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600640/how-to-save-a-3-channel-numpy-array-as-image). However, that works with mostly RGB style 3 channel images.

Comment: Is their another to save N number of 2D array of size (6,2840) instead of reshape the array. I want to save 3D array as multiple number of images

Comment: @nadamedhat, I would recommend checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228993/save-3d-array-into-a-stack-of-2d-images-in-python). If that doesn't help, and I am understanding your question incorrectly do inform me

Comment: It doesn't help me. I have multiple 2D arrays returned from wavelet function, I want to concatenate vertically those 2D array as an image.